# Redirecting the output of QProcess when running a resource file

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess, qresource

fairly new to Qt.

I'm using QProcess to run an external shell script and redirecting the output to a textBrowser on my GUI. Code:

In mainwindow.h:

```
private:
   QProcess *myProcess;
```

and mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::onButtonPressed(){
   myProcess = new QProcess(this);
   myProcess->connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(textAppend()));
   myProcess->start("./someScript.sh", arguments);
}

void MainWindow::textAppend(){
   ui->textBrowser->append(myProcess->readAll());
}
```

This works perfectly to run an external script. My question is how to apply the same process with the script included as a resource file.
I've tried simply replacing `"./someScript.sh"` with the resource version `":/someScript.sh"` but it does not seem to work.
The resource script runs perfectly, but the console output disappears.

Comment: What does it mean "does not seem to work"? Do you get the empty output? I would check the resoure file existence first with `QFile::exists(":/someScript.sh")`

Comment: The script executes (I can see that it does from other sources), but I get empty output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this reason, there is something called "**QTemporaryFile**" class.

Because you need to call a file that **already exists** in your system - ok!

let's take this example :

*using **QProcess** we need to **run a python file from resource***

```
//[1] Get Python File From Resource
QFile RsFile(":/send.py");
//[2] Create a Temporary File
QTemporaryFile *NewTempFile = QTemporaryFile::createNativeFile(RsFile);
//[3] Get The Path of Temporary File
QStringList arg;
arg << NewTempFile->fileName();
//[4] Call Process
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
myProcess->start("python", arg);
//[5] When You Finish, remove the temporary file
NewTempFile->remove();
```

> Note : on windows, the Temporary File stored in **%TEMP%** directory

and for more informations you can visit [Qt Documentation - QTemporaryFile Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtemporaryfile.html)

Good Luck ♥

Comment: High quality response, and the answerer's first post.

Answer (score 1):

I does not work because when you run `myProcess->start(":/someScript.sh", arguments);` you ask your system to run `:/someScript.sh` which does not exist for your system.

A quick solution would be to copy the script to a temporary folder and run it from there.

```
QFile::copy(":/someScript.sh", pathToTmpFile);
myProcess->start(pathToTmpFile, arguments);
```

I would also suggest you make use of `QTemporaryFile` to get a unique temporary file name.

Comment: The script runs, as I can see its results outside of my program. I just don't get the console output that I would when running it externally.

Comment: Check `QProcess:error()` and `QProcess::errorString()`. I've just test on ubuntu with Qt 5.6 and I have: QProcess::FailedToStart and "No such file or directory". Also I have absolutely no sign of the script ever being executed.